# Ruby on rails Haversine gem : convert calculated distance to km

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gps, haversine

I'm working on a task that calculate the distance between two gps points and I want to convert the distance to KM  :

```
def distances
    site     = Site.find params[ :id ]
    stores   = Store.current
    distances = []

    stores.map do |store|
      distance = Haversine.distance(site.address.latitude, site.address.longitude, store.address.latitude, store.address.longitude)
      distances << {
        name: store.name,
        value: distance
      }
    end

    render json: {
      distances: distances.to_json
    }

  end
```

example of calculated item :

> store2 : 5527.654499076738

in the doc of haversine gem there is a method to convert : distance.to_kilometers but it doesn't work for me ! any help ?

Comment: in which unit you're are getting the distance right now?

Comment: it's Haversine::Distance unit

Comment: how is it not working for you? What's it doing instead? Can you show how you tried calling it?

Comment: hi @SimpleLime : like that :       distance = Haversine.distance(site.address.latitude, site.address.longitude, store.address.latitude, store.address.longitude).to_kilometers

Comment: the distance variable should be Haversine::Distance as class type , but when checked it it's on Float < Numeric !

Comment: and from float, you can convert to any distance unit you want easily.

Comment: how that ? because i don't know this float returned in which unit it is !

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call the `to_kilometers` method on the resulting `Haversine::Distance` otherwise its `to_s` method will be used:

```
def distances
  site = Site.find params[ :id ]

  distances = Store.current.map do |store|
    {
      name: store.name,
      value: Haversine.distance(
               site.address.latitude,
               site.address.longitude,
               store.address.latitude,
               store.address.longitude
             ).to_kilometers
    }
  end

  render json: {
    distances: distances
  }
end
```

What you'll really want to do though is add a `distance_in_km` to your `Address` class...

Comment: in the gem documentation i found .to_kilometers method exist but that not work, it show an undefined method error

Comment: Have you forgotten to ```require 'haversine'```?